# All onion channels show HungryTREX as first node

Tags: tails, onion-routing

after upgrading to Tails 4.14, the first server in all onion channels is HungryTREX with an IP address from Toronto, Canada.

- This isn't looking sane, but what I do know...
- Many services are unavailable

Is that an expected behavior?

Comment: What's the question exactly? You're wondering if it's normal to have the same first relay in all circuits? If so, that is normal and you might want to read about [guard relays](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/faq#EntryGuards).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the pointer.